# Android post request (JSON parameter) to the WCF restful WS

Tags: android, json, wcf, wcf-rest

I am working on Android application and I have problem with my "POST" request (as usual) to my WCF Restful WS.

Restful method:

```
 [OperationContract]
 [WebInvoke(Method = "POST", RequestFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json, UriTemplate = "createUser")]
 string createUser(string user);
```

I order to find a error I put under the comment body of method implementation, and now it looks like:

```
public string createUser(string user)
        {
        return user;
        }
```

I have been calling this method a hundreds time from JS(jQuery, Ajax), with the JSON.stringify(datos), without the any problem.
Now I need to do same thing from android application.
This is probably snippet of my code which cause the problem:

```
JSONObject user =  new JSONObject();
user.put("id", "15");
user.put("name", "John");
user.put("city", "France");
user.put("email", "myemail");
user.put("password", "mypass");

HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
URI website = new URI("http://10.0.2.2/AutoOglasi/Service1.svc/createUser");
HttpPost request = new HttpPost();
request.setEntity(new StringEntity(user.toString()));
request.addHeader("content-type", "application/json");      
request.setURI(website);
HttpResponse response = client.execute(request);
```

I am getting the response from server (there is no error on my client side):

```
The exception message is 'There was an error deserializing the object of type
System.String. End element 'root' from namespace '' expected. Found element 'id' from
namespace ''.'.See server logs for more details. The exception stack trace is: </p> <p>at
System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.OperationFormatter.DeserializeRequest(Message message,
 Object[] parameters) at
System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.DemultiplexingDispatchMessageFormatter.DeserializeRequest(Me    ssage message, Object[] parameters) at
   System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.UriTemplateDispatchFormatter.DeserializeRequest(Message      message, Object[] parameters) at
System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.DispatchOperationRuntime.DeserializeInputs(MessageRpc&amp;      rpc) at
 System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.DispatchOperationRuntime.InvokeBegin(MessageRpc&amp; rpc) at
 System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.ImmutableDispatchRuntime.ProcessMessage5(MessageRpc&amp; rpc) at
System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.ImmutableDispatchRuntime.ProcessMessage31(MessageRpc&amp; rpc)
 at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.MessageRpc.Process(Boolean isOperationContextSet)</p> </div> </body></html>
```

Any advice or help, please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have funnily solved the problem:

1) I had to add BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.WrappedRequest to my service method to avoid error above. I do not really understand why, because it worked perfectly with jQuery Ajax call without BodyStyle parameter. I would appreciate if someone would explain it?

2)I used:  String s = "{\"id\":\"1\", \"name\":\"John\", \"user\":\"New Yourk\", \"email\":\"mypass\", \"password\":\"myemail\"}"; as a test string. I changed name of parameter "city" to user. I sent it to my service and as response I got "New Yourk", only one parameter which has a name as my WS method parameter.

It means that I need to send one parameter with name "user" and value. Something like:

```
 JSONObject userValue =  new JSONObject();
 JSONObject user =  new JSONObject();

 userValue .put("id", "15");
 userValue .put("name", "John");
 userValue .put("city", "France");
 userValue .put("email", "myemail");
 userValue .put("password", "mypass");

 user.put("user", userValue.toString());
```

Now my request is complete and my server side can process my user parameters.

Note: it is very important to add "userValue" as a string (user.put("user", userValue.toString())). If we add it as a Json (user.put("user", userValue)) it will not work.

Answer (score 0):

don't know if it has anything to do with this problem, but is the id supposed to be a string?

I'd guess should be this instead:

user.put("id", 15);

Comment: Sorry, I have just edit my last sentence, I am not getting the error, It is my response from server. I tried you advice, and nothing has change.

Comment: My parameter on server side is a string (JSON), which I supposed to parse, there is not any other type except string.